# Generating a Vapi file for a Vala library

Tags: vala, vapi

I've got a library written in Vala that has always worked fine generating a `.vapi` file for itself, I think because it's a free operation with `valac` but I'm not positive on that. I went and tried to use `VAPIGEN_CHECK` in my `configure.ac` file and the associated `VAPIGEN_MAKEFILE` in my `Makefile.am` and now I get:

```
error: The type name `GLib.TypeInstance' could not be found
```

My corresponding `.gir` file contains:

```
<field name="parent_instance">
  <type name="GObject.TypeInstance" c:type="GTypeInstance"/>
</field>
```

So the error seems to make sense because I can't find the `GObject.TypeInstance` class/struct in any `.vapi` file, but `GTypeInstance` is in one of the GLib headers.

Should I even be doing it this way if I'm writing everything in Vala already? Is there a possibility that this is missing from the Vapi?

Edit: Possibly just due to my not deriving `GLib.Object` which I thought was implicit. Still trying to fix something else that prevents this but once that's done I will update this to say whether or not it actually matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a VAPI file from a Vala program you should simply use the `--vapi` option with `valac`, e.g.:

`valac  --vapi my_library_name.vapi  my_library.vala`

From what you are describing I think you are generating a GIR (GObject Introspection Repository) file with `valac`, then using `vapigen` to create the VAPI file. `vapigen` is part of Vala and maintained in the Vala source code, but it is a tool for generating a VAPI file to bind to non-Vala projects. If the non-Vala project distributes a GIR file it makes the binding very easy.

When using `vapigen` you need to give the packages it uses, so you need to check you are including the right pkg-config flags, e.g.:

`vapigen --pkg glib-2.0 --pkg gobject-2.0 my_library.gir`

The other possibility is there is no binding for GTypeInstance in Vala. I've had a quick look and I'm not finding anything.

Comment: Using `--vapi` makes the most sense, explicitly setting `GLib.Object` as the base class did work though. I was just trying to generate the `.deps` using `vapigen`, which I did anyhow I just left out the rule for the Vapi.